# Как сделать копию activity или ссылку на него?

Tags: android

У меня есть два activity. В первом у меня список (listview), в котором при нажатии на его элемент я перехожу на третье activity, а второе пустое. Как сделать так, чтобы при **ЗАЖАТИИ** элемента списка (listview) в первом activity, во втором activity появлялась ссылка на третье activity.

Во многих приложениях с новостями, например, это работает как: "Добавить в избранное".

Comment: использовать ссылки на активити в других активити - плохо. Лобавляйте в избранное элемент списка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто храните где то список, который нужно отображать на второй активити. Например, в базе. Когда нужно "добавить на вторую активити" - просто добавляйте в базу. А когда пользователь захочет увидеть вторую активити - загрузите с базы нужный контент.

Comment: Может кто-то посоветует как это реализовать на примере или на какую-то статью (книгу) наведете?