# Как скопировать элемент списка (listview) из одного activity в другое?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть два activity. В первом у меня список (listview), в котором при нажатии на его элемент я перехожу на третье activity, а второе пустое. Как сделать так, чтобы при **ЗАЖАТИИ** элемента списка (listview) в первом activity, во втором activity появился элемент списка из первого activity.

Во многих приложениях с новостями, например, это работает как: "Добавить в избранное".

Может кто-то посоветует как это реализовать на примере или на какую-то статью (книгу) наведете?

Comment: создайте еще один точно такой же вопрос. Это решит вашу проблему.
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/425951/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8E-activity-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE

Comment: одного маловато будет. нужен десяток

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, в каком-нибудь классе `classOfArray` у Вас хранится ArrayList `Array1`, из которого вы создается `listView1` на первом активити.
Создаем там же новый пустой ArrayList `Array2`.

Первая активити:

```
listView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classOfArray.Array1)); // заполняем listview
listView1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
listView1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        classOfArray.Array2.add(classOfArray.Array1.get(position)); // добавляем во второй массив значение, на которое мы кликнули из первого массива
        return false;
    }
});
```

Вторая активити:

```
listView2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classOfArray.Array2)); // заполняем listview из второго массива
listView2.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!